Is there a better Way to Interact with UI Elements Using a Gamepad in C#? (SharpDX.XInput, RhinoCommon, Eto.Forms/WPF)
I’m working on a Rhino plugin in C# that allows users to interact with Rhino via a gamepad. I’m using the SharpDX.XInput library for gamepad input and RhinoCommon for Rhino API integration. For the UI, I can only use Eto.Forms or WPF.
I’ve successfully implemented viewport navigation using the gamepad, but now I need to interact with UI elements (e.g., buttons, sliders, dropdowns). Specifically, I want to use the gamepad to:

Navigate between UI elements.
Trigger actions (e.g., button clicks) with the gamepad buttons.
Adjust values in sliders and other input controls.

My Questions:

What’s the best way to map gamepad input to UI interactions in Eto.Forms or WPF?
Are there any libraries, patterns, or best practices that can help with making UI navigation intuitive and responsive using a gamepad?
How can I handle focus and selection changes between UI elements (such as buttons) using the gamepad's directional input?

You can check out the current state of the project on GitHub: Barn Owl Rhino Plugin.
Any examples or insights on how to implement gamepad-driven UI interactions in Eto.Forms or WPF would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I’ve tried both Eto.Forms and WPF for the UI, but I’m struggling with how to handle events and connect gamepad inputs to UI interactions. For example, how do I:

Focus or select UI elements using gamepad directional input?
Trigger button clicks or adjust slider values using gamepad events?
Handle focus changes and custom gamepad control for the UI?

